# GitLab merging changes from two branches

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have a current system of branches:

```
- deploy
- feature/1
```

I merged the branch `feature/1` to `deploy` with selecting "squash commits", but didn't delete the branch itself yet. Then I created a new branch `feature/2` from the `feature/1` (meaning that `feature/2` contains all the commits from `feature/1`). But now when I want to merge `feature/2` to `deploy` and create merge request it shows that all the changes from `feature/2` are conflicts and shows all the commits (with ones that were merged from `feature/1`), but I want it to be like in the first merge request, so it will show only the changes from `feature/2` that weren't in `feature/1` at the moment of the first merge to `deploy`.

I still have the merge request and the branch `feature/1`. How do I achieve something like this? There are two options available in the first merge request: "revert" and "cherry-pick", I read GitLab documentation on these buttons, but I'm still not sure what they do and what to pick in this situation.
If I need to draw it, it looks something like this:

```
---deploy------ok-------------?
----feature/1--|              |
                ---feature/2--|
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that when you merged feature/1 to develop, it left the branch feature/1 behind. To do what you are trying to achieve, I think you could create a new branch at the same commit as develop.

Comment: But I already created the branch from "feature/1", so it's not an option.

Comment: Are you only using the graphic interface of gitlab to make all of this ?

Comment: @polypode Yes, when it comes to merge requests, I'm using GUI.

Comment: Okay, but if I understood correctly, you already merged your two branches ?

Comment: I merged only first, but now need to merge second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238506/discussion-between-polypode-and-arzybek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch `deploy` already contains the changes of the `feature/1`. As the `feature/2` also contains the same changes, you get the merge conflicts.

In general, if after merging `feature/1` with `deploy` you create the `feature/2` from the `deploy` instead of `feature/1` the problem would not be there.

But since it's a bit late, I'd recommend the following easy approach:

1. Create another branch from the `deploy`, let's call it `feature/2.2`.
2. Cherry pick all the new commits of the `feature/2` (that are not part of `feature/1`) to the new branch.

Then you'll be able to easily merge the new branch with deploy.

---

Details:
Here's what it looks like in your current case:

```
deploy    => d1-d2-d3-f'------------f1-f2-f3-ff1-ff2-ff3
                     /             /?
feature/1 => f1-f2-f3             /?
                    |            /?  
feature/2 => f1-f2-f3-ff1-ff2-ff3
```

The branch `deploy` already contains the commit `f'` which is the squashed commit of `f1-f2-f3`.
So, if you try to merge `feature/2` with `deploy`, git will try to put the `f1-f2-f3-ff1-ff2-ff3` above the `f'` which already has the changes `f1-f2-f3`. And this is where you get merge conflicts.

Thus, to solve the problem we just create a new branch from `deploy` instead, so the `f1-f2-f3` are not there anymore, and just cherry-pick the other `ff1-ff2-ff3` which won't have merge conflicts. And then we can merge them back to deploy like this (by squashing `ff1-ff2-ff3` into `ff'`):

```
deploy      => d1-d2-d3-f'------------ff'
                        |             /
feature/2.2 => d1-d2-d3-f'-ff1-ff2-ff3
                          /   /    /
feature/2   => f1-f2-f3-ff1-ff2-ff3
                      |               
feature/1   => f1-f2-f3
```

Comment: Thanks, but will it work because I squashed commits?

Comment: If you're about the squashed commits of feature/1, then yes, it should work.